# Specify method name (for reflection) verifiable by compiler

Tags: c#

I'd like to call a method and supply some parameters (which I get from a filter control that returns name:value pairs) to it.

So if I have a method (on object obj) `string Foo(int bar, double baz)`, and a dictionary `{'bar':3,'baz':1.4}`, I'd like to write

`string s = Call<string>(obj,p=>p.Foo,dictionary)`

Is it possible somehow? Maybe with non-generic Delegate or something?
Or multiple generic Func static methods that will take advantage of c# type inference?

At this moment I have something like this:

```
    string s = Call<string>(obj,"Foo",parameters)
```

which is implemented as:

```
    TRet Call<TRet>(object target, string name, Dictionary<string, object> parameters) where TRet:class
    {
        var mi = target.GetType().GetMethod(name);
        object[] methodParameters = ConvertDictionaryToParameterArray(parameters);
        object o = mi.Invoke(target, methodParameters);
        return o as TRet;
    }
```

TRet Call(object target, string name, Dictionary parameters)

Somewhere else we have some reflection-based trickery that collects properties named Prop1,Prop2,Prop3,Prop4 into array Prop[], and the method can be called like `Collect(data, p=>Prop1)`, with definition of method Collect as `Wrapper<T> Collect<T>(T item, Expression<Func<T,int>> expr)`, analyzing the `expr` expression as MemberExpression.

Comment: Can you give an example of what this would be if you did it without reflection? As your question is a little unclear

Comment: There is no way to call method without reflection when you have his name and parameters as strings. Why don't you like your aproach ?

Comment: @IL_Agent possible create Expression tree, compile it and call, without using reflection directly

Comment: @Grundy, I don't think so, for expression tree you must have method but not his name and parameters as strings. If you know how could you show any proof please ?

Comment: I don't have a problem of calling the method without reflection, the only gripe is that I don't want to supply method name as string, but as a delegate / lambda expression

Comment: @IL_Agent for example this variant of [Expression.Call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336138(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Grundy, yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is probably:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
MethodInfo sort = Infoof(() => list.Sort());
MethodInfo binarySearch = Infoof(() => list.BinarySearch(null, null));

public static MethodInfo Infoof(Expression<Action> exp)
{
    return ((MethodCallExpression)exp.Body).Method;
}
```

It's a bit more verbose as you actually need to make a lambda that calls the method you need (note that it never actually performs the call itself).

More details:
http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2010/06/28/elegant-infoof-operators-in-c-read-info-of/

EDIT: If it's a static method with no return value, you know the input/output types or you don't mind specifying them explicitly you can also do:

```
MethodInfo write = ActionInfo(Console.WriteLine);
MethodInfo empty = FuncInfo(string.IsNullOrEmpty);
MethodInfo emptyT = FuncInfoT<string, bool>(string.IsNullOrEmpty);

public static MethodInfo ActionInfo(Action act)
{
    return act.Method;
}

public static MethodInfo FuncInfo(Func<string, bool> fn)
{
    return fn.Method;
}

public static MethodInfo FuncInfoT<T1, T2>(Func<T1, T2> fn)
{
    return fn.Method;
}
```

Comment: yes, but the problem is that when I have 15-parameter method generated by LINQ to SQL, I'd need to supply all parameters with some made up value. I was hoping that there is a way to just say (in your example) Infoof(()=> list.BinarySearch), but that probably wouldn't work

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately you can't get a reference directly to an instance method like that, so you'll always need the arguments if you want the compiler to help you validate it.